# Azure web role discards latest deploy after restart

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

When I deploy ASP.NET MVC application to Azure web role, after restarting of web role, all changes are discarded and some old files appear.

When Azure applies update to web role, it restarts web role, which means that latest version is not in web role.

Here is how it looks after latest deploy

[image]

When I reset manually web role (reset VM via Azure portal), those changes disappear. Here, I took screenshot of folder after reset and web deploy history from EventViewer.

[image]

I have this issue with multiple web/worker roles within different subscriptions.

Comment: How are you deploying the MVC application? I am assuming you're redeploying by uploading a new package file.

Comment: I'm uploading latest version using publish profile from VS